# How to fix: TypeError while trying to find a tag using xml.etree

Tags: python-3.x, xml.etree

I was running the following code to find some geodata. I thought that it would work, however, it always reports the following error when running on my machine:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ipgeo.py", line 25, in 
    region = tree.find('geoplugin_region').text()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable**

My code is supposed to get the public IP of the machine and retrieve some geographic data from this site: https://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/xml
I am able to get the XML data:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<geoPlugin>
        <geoplugin_request>122.174.62.125</geoplugin_request>
        <geoplugin_status>200</geoplugin_status>
        <geoplugin_delay>2ms</geoplugin_delay>
        <geoplugin_credit>Some of the returned data includes GeoLite data created by MaxMind, available from &lt;a href='http://www.maxmind.com'&gt;http://www.maxmind.com&lt;/a&gt;.</geoplugin_credit>
        <geoplugin_city>Chennai</geoplugin_city>
        <geoplugin_region>Tamil Nadu</geoplugin_region>
        <geoplugin_regionCode>TN</geoplugin_regionCode>
        <geoplugin_regionName>Tamil Nadu</geoplugin_regionName>
        <geoplugin_areaCode></geoplugin_areaCode>
        <geoplugin_dmaCode></geoplugin_dmaCode>
        <geoplugin_countryCode>IN</geoplugin_countryCode>
        <geoplugin_countryName>India</geoplugin_countryName>
        <geoplugin_inEU>0</geoplugin_inEU>
        <geoplugin_euVATrate></geoplugin_euVATrate>
        <geoplugin_continentCode>AS</geoplugin_continentCode>
        <geoplugin_continentName>Asia</geoplugin_continentName>
        <geoplugin_latitude>13.0833</geoplugin_latitude>
        <geoplugin_longitude>80.2833</geoplugin_longitude>
        <geoplugin_locationAccuracyRadius>50</geoplugin_locationAccuracyRadius>
        <geoplugin_timezone>Asia/Kolkata</geoplugin_timezone>
        <geoplugin_currencyCode>INR</geoplugin_currencyCode>
        <geoplugin_currencySymbol>&amp;#8377;</geoplugin_currencySymbol>
        <geoplugin_currencySymbol_UTF8>₹</geoplugin_currencySymbol_UTF8>
        <geoplugin_currencyConverter>68.7895</geoplugin_currencyConverter>
</geoPlugin>
```

But when I try to find the text from the the required tags (geoplugin_city, geoplugin_region, geoplugin_countryName) using the ET.find() function, I am getting a Type Error.

Here is the rest of the code:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import ssl
import urllib.error, urllib.parse, urllib.request

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

service_url = 'http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?'
ip_api = 'https://api.ipify.org'

ip_addr = urllib.request.urlopen(ip_api, context=ctx).read().decode() 
parms = dict()
parms['ip'] = ip_addr
url = service_url + urllib.parse.urlencode(parms)
print('Retrieving:',url)

xmldat = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read().decode()
print('Retrieved', len(xmldat), 'characters' )
print(xmldat)
tree = ET.fromstring(xmldat)

region = tree.find('geoplugin_region').text()
country = tree.find('geoplugin_countryName').text()
latitude = tree.find('geoplugin_latitude').text()
longitude = tree.find('geoplugin_longitude').text()
currency_exchange = tree.find('geoplugin_currencyConverter').text()

print('Region:', region, '\nCountry:', country, '\nLatitude', latitude, '\nLongitude:', longitude, '\nCurrency Exchange Rate (relative to US Dollar)', currency_exchange)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as the error says: 
`.text()` with the empty parentheses is a **function call** (I like to think of them as a `()` button you push to do something), where you are looking for an **object attribute** of the XML Etree element (no parens).

If you simply change all of them to `.text` without the parens, your code will work as expected.

I also recommend looking at [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) or [python's f-string syntax](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) for string formatting your `print` call—maybe something like this:

```
print(f"""
Region: {region}
Country: {country}
Latitude: {latitude}
Longitude: {longitude}
Currency Exchange Rate (relative to US Dollar): {currency_exchange}
""")
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm.